# spring boot change jackson dependancy version

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I am using spring boot version `2.3.2.RELEASE`. I am using jackson-annotations, jackson-databind, jackson-core, jackson-dataformat-xml with version 2.11.1.

I want to update jackson dependencies to 2.12.4.
spring-boot-starter internally uses jackson dependencies.
There are two ways I can achieve it

1. Only change used dependencies (jackson-annotations, jackson-databind, jackson-core, jackson-dataformat-xml) to version 2.12.4 but it will keep other dependencies inside spring-boot-start to 2.11.1. Will it cause any issue if some jackson lib with 2.11.1 and others with 2.12.4?
2. Change all jackson version using properties

   ```
   <jackson.version>2.12.4</jackson.version>
   <jackson-bom.version>2.12.4</jackson-bom.version>
   ```

   It will update all jackson dependencies to 2.12.4. Will upgrading lib version cause any issue in spring boot framework

Is it better to go with 2nd option?

Answer (score 4):

Defining just `<jackson-bom.version>2.12.4</jackson-bom.version>` in your POM should be fine usually (you don't need `<jackson.version>2.12.4</jackson.version>`). Upgrading Spring Boot to the current version (2.5.3 at the time of this writing), which also includes updated Jackson dependencies, would be even better though.